# How to express the Trinity in terms of category theory

Tags: trinity, philosophy

I've recently been studying [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) (mathematics), in which the relations between objects are generalized to a very abstract level. I was wondering therefore if the relations between the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit could be expressed in terms of concepts from category theory.

The explanations and analogies for the Trinity are often inadequate / oversimplified, but due to the nature of category theory I thought there may be a way to express the Trinity in terms of category theory.

This question of course calls for some background knowledge in category theory, which not everyone may have, but I appreciate any answers anyone can provide!

Comment: People have difficultly explaining the Trinity with words. It would be orders of magnitude more difficult to do so without words.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/81045/50422. Probably of interest: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/79273/48437

Comment: The revelation of the Deity is in the sending of the Son. If individuals do not hear His word and believe on him, they will have no understanding of the Deity. _Whosoever transgresseth, and abideth not in the doctrine of Christ, hath not God. He that abideth in the doctrine of Christ, he hath both the Father and the Son._ 2 John 1:9.

Comment: Would the answer be significantly different from the mathematics represented by the standard  "is"/"is not" tetrahedron  [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XmeW.png) ?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Category theory in the mathematic sense can't describe it any better than those analogies by definition. The terms used to describe the Trinity in part are developed because of the Categories of Aristotle (cf. Augustine's de Trinitate)

Comment: Good luck, you're gonna need it.

Comment: One issue you might find is that there isn't one theory of the Trinity within Trinitarianism. Rather, there are a bunch of them, which becomes clear once you start pushing on various issues related to it.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Still haven't recieived a good answer to my salvation objection since you ghosted that comment thread ;)

Comment: @LukeHill Can you link to your objection? I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather see the comment thread below steves answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/91338/56226

Comment: @LukeHill Heb 5:9?